# A vector with fixed correlation with existing vector, is it always possible?

Tags: correlation

Suppose we have a known vector $X$ in $R^n$,
and for any vector $Y$ in $R^n$, 
we impose on it the restriction that 
it must have a fixed correlation coefficient $r$
with $X$:

\begin{align*}
    \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_i-\overline{X}) (Y_i-\overline{Y})
}{
    \sqrt{
    \sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_i - \overline{X} )^2
    \sum_{i=1}^{n} (Y_i - \overline{Y} )^2
    }
} = r
\end{align*}

For simplicity we can assume $\overline{X} = \overline{Y} = 0$:

\begin{align}
\frac{
\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i Y_i
}{
    \sqrt{
\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i^2
\sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i^2
}
} = r
\end{align}

If we fix $y_1, y_2, \cdots, y_{n-1}$ and let $y_n$ vary,
then Eq. \ref{20130901corr} can be turned into
a quadratic equation,
and for it to have a solution,
the discriminant must satisfy $\Delta \ge 0$,
which gives us the following inequality:

\begin{align}
    \label{20130901delta}
r^2
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} X_i^2
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} Y_i^2
-(1 - r^2)
X_n^2
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} Y_i^2
&\le
(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} X_i Y_i)^2
\end{align}

Notice that when $r^2 = 1$, this 
is just Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in the reverse 
direction, so the two sides must be equal,
which can be true if and only if
$Y = kX$.

When we allow more elements of $Y$ to vary, 
things gets a bit more complicated, 
but it still boils down to a second 
degree polynomial with multiple variables.

When $n=10$, and allowing three 
elements of $Y$ to vary, 
this can be visualized in a
3D Cartesian coordinate system in Mathematica:

```
SeedRandom[17]
x = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 10]
y = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 7]
expr = Re[Correlation[x, Join[y, {y1, y2, y3}]]]
ContourPlot3D[
 expr == 0.1, {y1, -200, 200}, {y2, -300, 300}, {y3, -400, 400}]
ContourPlot3D[
 expr == 0.3, {y1, -200, 200}, {y2, -300, 300}, {y3, -400, 400}]
ContourPlot3D[
 expr == 0.5, {y1, -200, 200}, {y2, -300, 300}, {y3, -400, 400}]
ContourPlot3D[
 expr == 0.7, {y1, -200, 200}, {y2, -300, 300}, {y3, -400, 400}]
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

The shape of the cap-shaped surface gets increasingly sharper
as $r$ gets larger, 
making one wonder whether it will still be possible 
if $r$ gets very close to 1.

Comment: Now posted to MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/141087/a-vector-with-fixed-correlation-with-existing-vector-is-it-always-possible

Comment: You should have square roots in your denominator. If $X=(1,0,0,0,0,0)$, then $Y=(r,\sqrt{1-r^2},0,0,0,0)$ will do the trick.